# Inherit new theme from blank theme

Tags: orocommerce, orocrm

Is it allowed to create new theme with parent theme as blank in Orocommerce v5.1? When I am trying to do that, I got error "Unable to retrieve definition for theme blank".
If it isn't possible, how would be better to create custom theme from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Since 5.1 `blank` theme has been removed. For this reason you are able to create a custom theme with a [parent as `default`](https://doc.oroinc.com/frontend/storefront/theming/#theme-definition) one.